# Fixing formatting errors created by long eqnarrays

Tags: equations, page-breaking

I'm writing a paper in which I have long `eqnarray`s, many of them 10 lines or longer. Since TeX seems to not want to page-break these equations, this results in weird formatting, eg pages that have large amounts of whitespace and not much actual text. Is there any way to force TeX to page-break `eqnarray` equations in a natural way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Here is a related question that might be helpful: [custom alignment of columns in align environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38427/custom-alignment-of-columns-in-align-environment)

Comment: Don't use the `eqnarray` environment; instead, load the `amsmath` package and use its `align` environment. To allow page breaks, issue the statement `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Avoid `eqnarray`!](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen) Use the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package and its `align` environment to replace `eqnarray`. The `\allowdisplaybreaks` command in the preamble of your document will enable page breaks within equation arrays.

Comment: As `\allowdisplaybreaks` will allow page break after any line in a display environment, its use should be limited to document preparation; for the final version, suitably chosen `\displaybreak` commands should be used at the spots where page breaks are more convenient.

Comment: Just to add, with `align`, you specify **only one** `&` for each line, and it has to be **on the left** from the equals sign, like `\begin{align} f(x) &= x^2 \\ g(x) &= \sqrt x \end{align}

Comment: Wow, thanks! That was fast. Okay, sounds good: I'll try the align environment.