# How can I allow gather to break between pages?

Tags: equations, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom alignment of columns in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38427/custom-alignment-of-columns-in-align-environment)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1-4]

\lipsum[4]
\begin{gather}
\dfrac{1}{a} = a ^ {-1} \\
\dfrac{1}{b} = b ^ {-1} \\
\dfrac{1}{c} = c ^ {-1} \\
\dfrac{1}{d} = d ^ {-1} \\
\dfrac{1}{e} = e ^ {-1}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Some of the equations could fit on the first page. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: `\displaybreak`?

Comment: `\allowdisplaybreaks` -- see mathmode

Comment: @Marco Although the solution to the linked question is the same, there's no mention of `gather` in that question, so I'm not sure this one should be closed. This question is also a simpler one, so it would be useful to have an answer to it.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel While `\allowdisplaybreaks` does the job, it acts "globally" and the finer control that can be achieved with `\displaybreak` can give better results in the final revision of an important document.

Comment: @egreg: I know -- but you mention `displaybreak` and I `allowdisplaybreaks`. The mention document `mathmode` finished it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To quote from p. 6 of the [amsmath user guide](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) (note that `gather` is an environment provided by the `amsmath` package):

> When the `amsmath` package is in use page breaks between equation
> lines are normally disallowed; the philosophy is that page breaks in such
> material should receive individual attention from the author. To get an individual
> page break inside a particular displayed equation, a `\displaybreak`
> command is provided. `\displaybreak` is best placed immediately before the
> `\\` where it is to take effect. Like LATEX’s `\pagebreak`, `\displaybreak` takes
> an optional argument between `0` and `4` denoting the desirability of the pagebreak.
> `\displaybreak[0]` means "it is permissible to break here" without encouraging
> a break; `\displaybreak` with no optional argument is the same as
> `\displaybreak[4]` and forces a break.

> If you prefer a strategy of letting page breaks fall where they may, even in the
> middle of a multi-line equation, then you might put `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]`
> in the preamble of your document. An optional argument `1–4` can be used for
> finer control: `[1]` means allow page breaks, but avoid them as much as possible;
> values of `2`,`3`,`4` mean increasing permissiveness. When display breaks are
> enabled with `\allowdisplaybreaks`, the `\\*` command can be used to prohibit
> a pagebreak after a given line, as usual.

Comment: "the`\\*` command can be used to prohibit a pagebreak after a given line" - the beauty of TeX.SX: be prepared to learn something new from each sentence, even the final oh-I-nearly-forgot-to-mention subclause.