# How to break (long) equation latex?

Tags: equations, line-breaking, page-breaking

when I'm almost at the end of the page and I insert a long equation (a few lines), Latex prefers to leave some white space at the end of the page, and writes the whole equation in the next page.

***Is is possible to break long equations such that part of it is at the end of page N and the rest continues in page N+1?***

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you want to *break* rather than *not to break*

Comment: lol you are right......

Comment: How are you inputting such a long equation? With `align` or similar environment?

Comment: I use `aligned` , is it causing the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I allow gather to break between pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57338)

Comment: Does this help: [Using \allowdisplaybreaks locally for a single chapter / single equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102173) ?

Comment: Go for @barbarabeeton 's link, that helped me once!

Comment: `with aligned (nested inside equation) this is not possible. With `align`,  this is possible by write `\allowdisplaybreaks` in document preamble or locally before  in groups with `align`.

Comment: With `\allowdisplaybreaks` and `aligned`, for every line it gives me one equation (A.1, A.2, A.3, ...), which I dont want. With instead `align*`, It also works but it doesnt name the equation at all. So now I'm confused... Because I would like to enumerate it as if it were written with `\begin{equation}` ... `\end{equation}`.

Comment: If you *really* want a multi-line equation with a single equation number to break across pages, then use `align` and put `\notag` on every line where the number shouldn't appear.  (But this is considered bad style.)  Other possible options are to (1) increase/decrease the page size with `\enlargethispage`, rewrite some text to change the length of preceding paragraphs, or (3) reset some preceding paragraphs to be shorter or longer (using `\looseness`) to change the location of the page break.  If (1) or (3) seems acceptable, those have already been covered in other questions.

Comment: Thanks Barbara!!! Given that it happens once in the entire file, the `\notag` really makes the trick and thank you very very much..

Comment: ps. I agree with you that is very very very bad style..but...it works :-)