# Latex leaves first page blank and text goes outside page from the bottom

Tags: mactex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newgeometry{vmargin={15mm}, hmargin={12mm}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathleft}{\@fleqntrue\@mathmargin0pt}
\newcommand{\mathcenter}{\@fleqnfalse}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\fontsize{18}{21.6}
\mathleft
\begin{gather*}
    8x^2+10x-3=0\\\\
    8x^2-2x+12x-3=0\\\\
    2x(4x-1)+3(4x-1)=0\\\\
    (2x+3)(4x-1)=0\\\\
    x=-\frac{3}{2}\;or\;\frac{1}{4}\\\\\\\\\\\\
    -7x^2-4x+3=0\\\\
    -7x^2-7x+3x+3=0\\\\
    -7x(x+1)+3(x+1)=0\\\\
    (3-7x)(x+1)=0\\\\
    x=\frac{3}{7}\;or\;-1\\\\\\\\\\\\
    x^2+4=8x-8\\\\
    x^2-8x+12=0\\\\
    x^2-2x-6x+12=0\\\\
    x(x-2)+-6(x-2)=0\\\\
    (x-6)(x-2)=0\\\\
    x=2\;or\;6
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

When I run this code I get a pdf with the first page blank and some of the actual text outside the page. How can I fix it so that it does not leave a blank page and the text stays in the page so that if it can't fit it creates a new page and puts the text there. Both of these issues disappear if the text between begin gather and end gather is small, but how do I make it work regardless of the amount of text or size of the font? The question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227344/first-page-blank-latex) but I am not using the xcolor package or counters. To get the pdf I am using the TexShop application installed from mactex.

Comment: `\\\\ ` (four in a row) doesn't seem right.  12 is definitely wrong.  If it's a separate display, then end the `gather*` and start a new one.

Comment: `\fontsize{18}{21.6}` does not select a font, you need `\selectfont` after it.

Comment: Also, you probably want to use `\text{ or }` rather than `\;or\;`

Comment: Off topic: if using both `amsmath` and `amsthm`, `amsmath` should always be loaded first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content won't fit the page at that font size, and `gather` won't allow a page break.  You can add `\allowdisplaybreaks[1]` to your preamble to change this behavior.  See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57344